# could not parse as YAML: yaml: line 102: did not find expected key

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I'm trying to create a github workflow yaml to build a x86_64-pc-linux-gcc toolchain but I keep getting an error "could not parse as YAML: yaml: line 102: did not find expected key yaml-syntax" but I can't seem to find the problem.

here's the link to my yaml:

https://github.com/7dog123/GCC-toolchain/blob/master/.github/workflows/cygwin.yml

Comment: Please don't post links to external code only, transform your code into an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead and make sure your question is self-contained. If you feel like you want to add the link for additional context, at least make it a ["perma"link](https://github.com/7dog123/GCC-toolchain/blob/9bbf161bcaaf2b6a51f8ec7e5531f581098abbc7/.github/workflows/cygwin.yml).

Comment: Apart from indentation issues, the `id: _cache` is also missing from the cache step that is being used later. Always lint your workflows with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to catch and fix syntax issues quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your YAML has several errors.

For example, here:

```
    - name: configure GCC
      run: |
       cd gcc
       mkdir gcc-${{ env.TARGET_ALIAS }}
      ## On x86_64 hosts, set the default directory name for 64-bit libraries to “lib”
       case $(uname -m) in
         x86_64)
       ...
```

The line starting with `#` doesn't match the indentation above, which ends the literal string block.

This same error occurs several times throughout the document, at time of writing:

- On [line 107](https://github.com/7dog123/GCC-toolchain/blob/ada3a05160fffe27307cf3b18429c1335824737b/.github/workflows/cygwin.yml#L107)
- On [lines 124-128](https://github.com/7dog123/GCC-toolchain/blob/ada3a05160fffe27307cf3b18429c1335824737b/.github/workflows/cygwin.yml#L124-L128)
- On [lines 169-170](https://github.com/7dog123/GCC-toolchain/blob/ada3a05160fffe27307cf3b18429c1335824737b/.github/workflows/cygwin.yml#L169-L170)
- On [lines 186-188](https://github.com/7dog123/GCC-toolchain/blob/ada3a05160fffe27307cf3b18429c1335824737b/.github/workflows/cygwin.yml#L186-L188)